# Where to start for developing mobile application?

Tags: mobile-application

I know this is repeated question. I read almost all the threads , googled a lot and  became more confused. I read Microsoft Mobile Internet Toolkit (MMIT) is not used anymore and Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit is widely used .

Requirement:Develope and publish websites for mobile phones.

Envoirnment:VS2008/.net 3.5

I am new to mobile web application development. I want to know how to start ,what are the frameworks i should know/download,sample websites or articles..

Thanks,
Vanitha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create web applications for mobile devices using microsoft technologies check out this site:

http://www.asp.net/mobile

It has simple how-to.....

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to invest in a new skill, I'd focus on iPhone and Android development - they're far more widespread than windows mobile.